# How do I store my site user's email addresses in both Aweber my MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, email

My web site has an opt-in form for user's email addresses. The form will have fields such as name, email and phone number.

Upon submission, I would like the data to also be inserted into my MySQL database.

However, I would also like the email address to be added to an AWeber email subscriber list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Yes, it is posible to store the data in a database.

Posting data via a 3rd party script [is against Awebers Terms of Service](http://www.aweber.com/faq/questions/268/Can+I+Submit+Subscribers+to+AWeber+via+Another+Script?). So it is necessary to take another route.

The way to do it is to allow your user to submit their information to Aweber via the JavaScript form, but choose the setting to **request that Aweber send the user information back to you, via your thank you page**.

You can use the thank you page to store the user data in your database.